# update sqlite database file from remote server with url

Tags: android, database, sqlite, download, synchronization

I have an sqlite database stored in the internal storage of my app.

I want my app to check whether a .db file has changed from a url to the file. If it has then it has to download that file and replace that file with the one it has in its internal database storage. How do I go on about implementing this? I can't pay for hosting but plan to use www.fileswap.com for it. Please help.

I have already considered upload.com but they want full software not a small database file. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: if you have API available of your hosting server so you can check with modified date with your last fetched file date and if there is difference than you can download file from url and update the last fetched file date into your database for future check...

Comment: that's what I was thinking. Use google spreadsheet, and store the last modified date within the sqlite database, if that has changed, then get the data from the spreadsheet. But can't I just use the .db file for this? can you give me an option available for this please?

Comment: i dont get exactly what you want to do...the first thing you need to check that DB file is updated than you have to use your own server space(server side code) which can track your server side activity and by using which you can detect updated file.... or second way is to use Very good hosting site which provide you APIs by using which you can detect activity of your particular space.. If you have server API so you can check with db file size or last modified date etc etc..

Comment: Du have any suggestions for these hosting sites? I need one that is free of charge.

Comment: sorry i never used hosting sites...i always worked on own custom server..